# iOS layer animation - explanation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

```
let flyRight = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
flyRight.toValue = view.bounds.size.width/2
flyRight.duration = 0.5
flyRight.fromValue = -view.bounds.size.width/2
flyRight.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
flyRight.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 3.4
password.layer.position.x = view.bounds.size.width/2
password.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)
```

My question is: how is it possible that before I am adding the animation, I first put the layer at the end position, but when the app goes up, I don't see it there before the animation starts? Instead, the animation works after 3.4 seconds as expected.

I mean, how iOS knows that first it needs to run the animation and only then put the layer to it's final position?

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the way UI changes get applied. When you make a change to a UI object, that change is not rendered to the screen until your code returns and the event loop runs.

When that happens, the system moves your view to it's final position, but then the ACTUAL view/layer hierarchy gets covered with a new layer that's drawn on top, known as the presentation layer. The presentation layer is where the pixels from the animation show up on the screen. That's what you see.

When the animation finishes, the presentation layer is hidden/removed (not honestly sure which) and the actual layer contents are shown. At that point the layer is in it's final position, so everything looks correct.

Comment: So change to a UI object is not rendered immediatley. Got it.
Still, I don't understand what happens behind the scenes when the code returns? the view should be placed in it's final position, and only 3.4 sceonds later I should see it starting animating. What's hidding it before the animation runs? Presentation layer only effective when the animation runs, so how can it cover the model layer of the view?

Comment: Is it related to the fact that I am using fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth ?
This making the first frame of animation apeear regardless of when the animation should start/

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, the view being animated is covered by the presentation layer, thus cannot respond to any touches, correct? Until the animation finishes, the animated view is not responding to touches, and is outside of the responder chain. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is because there is a `presentationLayer` and a `modelLayer` so animation show and modify `presentationLayer`, so `presentationLayer` is like a ghost.

> You probably know that UIView instances, as well as layer-backed NSViews, modify their layer to delegate rendering to the powerful Core
>   Animation framework. However, it is important to understand that
>   animations, when added to a layer, don’t modify its properties
>   directly.
>       Instead, Core Animation maintains two parallel layer hierarchies: the model layer tree and the presentation layer tree.
>        Layers in the former reflect the well-known state of the layers, wheres only layers in the latter approximate the in-flight values of
>   animations.
>       Consider adding a fade-out animation to a view. If you, at any point during the animation, inspect the layer’s opacity value, you
>   most likely won’t get an opacity that corresponds to what is onscreen.
>   Instead, you need to inspect the presentation layer to get the correct
>   result.
>       While you may not set properties of the presentation layer directly, it can be useful to use its current values to create new
>   animations or to interact with layers while an animation is taking
>   place.
>       By using -[CALayer presentationLayer] and -[CALayer modelLayer], you can switch between the two layer hierarchies with ease.

you can find more info here https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/

I hope this helps you