# How to select annotation when it is animating (Swift MapKit)

Tags: ios, animation, select, annotations, mapkit

In iOS 10.1, swift 3 I have added some annotations (cars) on my Apple Map. I made them move by using `animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Void)`.

I want to show information when we tap on the cars, but the event `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` is not work when the cars are moving. I guess that only works when the cars don't move (I have tried).

Then I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` into Map to detect tapped coordinate and check it is near by the cars' coordinate or not. That works. However, it only works when we tap near by the cars. If we tap inside the cars, it does not work.

I hope you can give me a solution for this case.
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

In func `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` before return a `MKAnnotationView` I set property `isUserInteractionEnabled` false. The `UITapGestureRecognizer` works perfectly.

But I want to know how to select **Animating annotation**. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819903/ios-layer-animation-explanation/37820225#37820225 maybe can help you

Comment: check this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818440/update-views-frame-while-its-being-animated/37819789#37819789 can you share your code?

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian. But sorry I can't share my code. I'll see that when I have time.